# ВебСокеты через HTTPS, обычный хостинг

Tags: безопасность, websocket, https

Как сделать связку HTTPS сайта и вебсокетов?

Читал что можно использовать защищенный протокол для соединения. Не понимаю как это делается на практике. Я писал приложение (для другого проекта) на C# с использованием сторонней библиотеки вебсокетов: Отдельный процесс работает на сервере и принимает TCP соединения на определенный порт, а дальше уже работа производится через протокол. Но это никак не затрагивает именно веб сервер (*IIS Apache и т.п.* не знают о существовании такого процесса и не имеют инструкций для работы с ним).

Нашел реализацию вебсокетов на PHP (*Ratchet?*)

```
$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new WsInheritedClass()//имя нашего класса, определяется пользователем
        )
    ),
    8080
);
$server->run();
```

Запускается этот скрипт посредством команды `>php script.php` и работает до ручной отмены (т.е. бесконечно)

**Вопрос:** Каким образом сделать связку обычного веб сайта по HTTPS и защищенного соединения вебсокетов `wss://domain.com:port/uri` ?